# How to make a SQLite Trigger convert a JSON array of objects into new records?

Tags: json, sqlite, triggers, sql-insert

I try to make a Trigger in SQLite (BEFORE or AFTER INSERT) which takes this new row:

```
** events table **
id   timeslots
1    [{start: 2023, end: 2024 }, { start: 2025, end: 2025 }, ...]
```

and save it into this other table:

```
** timeslots table **
id   end   start
1    2023  2024
1    2024  2025
1    ...   ...
```

At this time, my not-working Trigger is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS insert_timeslots
  AFTER INSERT ON events
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO timeslots (id, start, end)
    SELECT 
      json_extract(t.value, '$.id'),
      json_extract(t.value, '$.start'),
      json_extract(t.value, '$.end'),
    FROM json_each(NEW.timeslots) AS t;
END;`
```

I've start a [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9LkhtmYq) to help debugging.
Any clue? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` is not part of the json array:

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS insert_timeslots AFTER INSERT ON events
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO timeslots (id, start, end)
  SELECT NEW.id,
         json_extract(t.value, '$.start'),
         json_extract(t.value, '$.end')
  FROM json_each(NEW.timeslots) AS t;
END;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/EEEjOzka).